# get the value of decision trees in random forests

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

Is it possible to know which number of trees get to me the predicted value?
I made an object detection project using the random forests algorithm

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
RF_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 50, random_state = 42)

# Train the model on training data
RF_model.fit(X_for_RF, y_train)
```

Here I have 50 trees, and I need to know which number of trees get to me this predicted value.

assume random forest extract to me this is apple then i need to get the number of trees it dcided it apple like "*there are 30 trees tell me this is apple and the other 20 decide it banana*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible using the `estimators_` attribute:

```py
RF_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 50, random_state = 42)
RF_model.fit(X_for_RF, y_train)

trees = RF_model.estimators_
# Get all 50 tree predictions for the first instance
preds_for_0 = [tree.predict(X_for_RF[0].reshape(1, -1))[0] for tree in trees]
```

Here `trees` is a list of `n_estimators` (here *50*) `DecisionTreeClassifier()` objects from `sklearn.tree`. To get the class labels from each tree, you can simply use the `predict()` method.

The list `preds_for_0` (of length *50*) stores the labels predicted for `X_for_RF[0]` by each constituent tree. Exploring this list will easily give you the majority label and also which tree gave what label to the instance.